# Recursive Function to Return Directory Depth

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to write recursive scripts in bash that receive as an argument a single path and prints the depth of the directory tree rooted at this path.

This is the `list_dirs.sh` script:

```
ls -l $dir | grep  dr..r..r..  | sed 's/.*:...\(.*\)/\1/'
```

And this is the `isdir.sh` script:

```
if [ -d $1 ]; then
echo 1
elif [ -e $1 ]; then
echo 0
else
echo -1
fi
```

They both work good.

This is the script `dir_depth.sh` that I wrote that doesn't work:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Usage: ./dir_depth.sh <path>"
  exit1
fi

x=`source isdir.sh $1`
if [ $x -eq -1 ]; then
  echo "no such path $1"
fi
dir=$1
maxD=0
dirs=`source list_dirs.sh`
for f in $dirs
do
  if [ $x -ne 0 ]; then
    x=`dir_depth.sh $f`
    if [ "$x" -eq "$maxD" ]; then
      maxD=x;
    fi
  fi
  echo $f
done
echo $((maxD++))
```

I'm really new to bash scripting and I don't know how to debug or what's wrong in my script.

Comment: edit your Q to include a sample of the dir you need to process and the required output from your script. Otherwise we have to guess ;-/ , right? use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some missing items are:

1. If you have a directory `parent/child/` and run `list_dirs.sh parent/`, it will output `child`. You then try to look up `child/` in the current directory instead of `parent/child/`.
2. You do `echo $f` for debug purposes and `echo $((maxD++))` to return a result. They are being confused for each other. Use `>&2` to write errors and debug messages to stderr.
3. `echo $((maxD++))` is a classic error equivalent to `return x++`. You return the number, and then increment a variable that's no longer used.
4. `[ "$x" -eq "$maxD" ]` makes no sense. Use `-ge` since you're trying to find the max.

Here's dir_depth.sh with these changes in place:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Usage: ./dir_depth.sh <path>" >&2
  exit 1
fi

x=`source ./isdir.sh $1`
if [ $x -eq -1 ]; then
  echo "no such path $1" >&2
fi
dir=$1

dirs=`source ./list_dirs.sh`
maxD=0
for f in $dirs
do
  if [ $x -ne 0 ]; then
    x=`./dir_depth.sh "$1/$f"`
    if [ "$x" -ge "$maxD" ]; then
      maxD="$x";
    fi
  fi
  echo $f >&2
done
echo $((maxD+1))
```

Comment: Why do you transfer the current dir in the loop like this:  "$1/$f" ? 
When you calling the script in recursion... Why do you need the $1?

Comment: This is point #1. Try `mkdir -p one/two` to create two directories inside each other. Then `ls one` will show `two` but `ls two` will say it's not found. You have to combine the root and the child directory